# Can not start puppet due to a missing file

Tags: puppet

I just installed Puppet using Homebrew on OS X, but unfortunately, when I try to run `puppet`, I get an error message about a file that could not be loaded. As I have absolutely no experience with Ruby, I don't know what to look for or what to search for (except the error message itself, which brings too many results, so I don't know which direction to follow).

Ruby itself is installed, as far as I can tell. At least the `irb` command takes me to an interactive shell where I can run

```
puts "Hello world!"
```

successfully. Can anybody give me some hints on what to do?

The error message is as follows:

```
schneehase:~ golo$ puppet
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/
  rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file
  to load -- facter (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/
  1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/puppet.rb:6
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/
  1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/
  1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:12
from /usr/bin/puppet:3:in `require'
from /usr/bin/puppet:3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Ruby installation. 1.8 is outdated and I had a lot of similar error messages as long as I used the pre-installed version of Ruby. You can use `rvm` to upgrade to the current version of Ruby with this [tutorial](http://www.rickypai.com/blog/2013/02/24/web-dev-upgrading-ruby-2-0-on-rvm-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-10-8-2/).

Comment: Hm, didn't work for me. Already the second command (`rvm requirements run`) fails with an error :-/. It complains about local changes that would be overwritten by a merge. Sounds like git, but I don't have the slightest idea of what to do with this error …